# PostgreSQL: find out if a row has been created by the current transaction

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, commit

Is it possible to find out if a row in a table has been created by the current transaction (and therefore is not yet visible for other transactions, because the current transaction is still active)?

My use case: I am adding event logging to the database. This is done in plpgsql triggers. A row in the event table looks like this: `(event id:serial, event action:text, count:integer:default 1)`.

Now, the reasoning behind my question: If a certain row has been created by this transaction (most likely in another trigger), I could increment the count instead of creating a new row in the event table.

Comment: What is your actual use case? Your question screams "race condition" and "integrity issue".

Comment: If your code is creating the rows, why don't you make it track the rows it create? This way you don't even query the database again, your code can send an UPDATE right away.

Comment: This is done in **several** plpgsql triggers. So I could either keep track of the rows which events have been created (temporary table? timestamp column?) or even better, find out somehow. Hence my question.

Comment: I guess you could add a transaction id field to your logging and save `txid_current()`. Perhaps use `ON CONFLICT` when logging.

Comment: Thank you. But how does the database keep track of the rows impacted by the current transaction? Somehow, the database needs the same information, to be able to commit or rollback. Is it possible for me to access that information? If so, I don't need to manually save the transaction id as you suggested and bloat my schema (personal feeling)?

Comment: It might already exist actually. You should look into [system columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html). `xmin` and `xmax` look promising. The whole idea is hackish as hell though.

Comment: Why is it hackish as hell?

Comment: You mean, why is it hackish to implement logging right into your schema, using database-dependent, database-version-dependent internals, relying on system columns and adding application-level logic in the database? Well…

Comment: Oh well. Sorry for asking. In essence, you are stating that I should forgo plpgsql triggers to add any kind of application/logging logic and be done with it. **No**

Comment: I didn't say you should stop, I don't know your context; I said it is hackish and I would not do it, especially if you start using system columns and engine internals. That is code waiting to break anytime. At least be sure to document abundantly for whoever will have to maintain that.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using triggers for auditing or event tracking, that's one of the use cases. My comment is more along the lines of: Where is the timestamp? Where is the userID? If the timestamp, userID and event action text are the same then it's the same event, otherwise not.

Comment: @Ben: Isn't it possible to have 2 subsequent transactions with the same timestamp?

Comment: You can use a sequence as well/instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just look for logging entries like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM tablename
WHERE xmin = current_txid() % (2^32)::bigint;
```

That will find all rows added or modified in the current transaction.

The downside is that this will force a sequential scan of the whole table, and you cannot avoid that since you cannot have an index on a system column.

So you could add an extra column `xid` to your table that is filled with `txid_current()::bigint` whenever a row is inserted or updated. Such a column can be indexed and efficiently used in a search:

```
SELECT ...
FROM tablename
WHERE xid = current_txid();
```

Comment: Thank you. I will think about adding the `xid` column.

Comment: I believe the following check is also valid to avoid false positives? `xmin::text = (txid_current() % (2^32)::bigint)::text;` (without the need of your `xid` column) I found it on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146315/how-to-compare-xmin-and-txid-current-after-transactions-id-wraparound

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake there. `current_txid()` does *not* return the same values as `xmin` contains. I have fixed (and simplified) the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider something like this:

```
create table ConnectionCurrentAction (
     connectionID int primary key,
     currentActionID uuid
)
```

then at the beginning of the transaction:

```
delete ConnectionCurrentAction where connectionID = pg_backend_pid()
insert ConnectionCurrentAction(connectionID, currentActionID) 
select pg_backend_pid(), uuid_generate_v4()
```

You can wrap this in a proc called say, `audit_action_begin`

**Note:** You may instead choose to enforce the requirement that an "action" be created explicitly by removing the delete here.

At the end of a transaction, do `audit_action_end`:

```
delete ConnectionCurrentAction where connectionID = pg_backend_pid()
```

Whenever you want to know the current transaction:

```
(select currentActionID from ConnectionCurrentAction where connectionID - pg_backend_pid()(
```

You can wrap that in a function `audit_action_current()`

You can then put the currentActionID into your log which will enable you to identify whether a row was created in the current action or not. This will also allow you to identify where rows in different audit tables were created in the current logical action.

If you don't want to use a uuid a sequence would do just as well here. I like uuids.

Comment: Great ideas! This is very useful. One question though: why are you using `pg_backend_pid()` and not `txid_current()`? Just wondering if there is a good reason for that... Thanks again.

Comment: Excellent question. Because I didn't know about `txid_current()`. Now I do :-) With that you don't really need this answer, just bung that into your audit table.

Comment: Unless of course you have logical "application" actions which are distinct from postgresql transactions

Comment: Great. We still need to care of the `xid` wraparound, but this is clearly explained in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146315/how-to-compare-xmin-and-txid-current-after-transactions-id-wraparound and comments.

Comment: `Unless of course you have logical "application" actions which are distinct from postgresql transactions`: Currently that is not the case, but I understand what you mean. Thanks for pointing out.